# Calling complete() on automatic variable of type struct completion defined in "waiting" thread

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I try to understand use of completion in a piece of code.

Basically, one kernel thread creates automatic variable struct completion which is, I assume, allocated on the thread's stack. Then it pushes pointer of the completion struct to another thread (using fifo) and waits for completion.

```
struct completion done;

init_completion(&done);
push_to_fifo(&done);
wait_for_completion(&done);
```

The second thread fetches request from fifo, processes it and completes task.

Will the done variable be accessible from the second thread which calls complete(done)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thread is waiting for the second to finish, so the `struct completion` on its stack will be stable until after `wait_for_completion` returns.

The stack space where that structure resides is just regular memory, the same as heap-allocated memory. The only difference is that once this function returns, and its caller invokes a different function, the same memory gets re-used for the stack frame / local variables of that next function.

So, if the other thread were to access the structure after that point, that would be a problem, but the point is that is supposed to be finished by then and once it signals "done", it shouldn't touch that memory again.

Comment: Let me conclude. if I understood well. As we are executing both threads in the same address space (kernel virtual address space, no need to change address mapping in context switch) then the local variable is still available until it waits. After return obviously the local function stack will be "freed". That makes sense. Thanks.